# Jquery recursive selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, truncate

I have whole bunch of `<div class="productlistname"><a href="#">The Text!</a></div>`. What I want to do go through all `.productlistname` and truncate the text and replace the current text with the truncated version.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(".productlistname a").html($(".productlistname a").html().substring(0,10));
```

This just truncate the first one and replaces the rest of .productlistname with the truncated version of the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".productlistname a").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().substring(0,10));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".productlistname a").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().substring(0,10));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".productlistname a").each(functon(){
  // loopy loop
});
```